# issue updating squeel with active admin, polyamorous, activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, squeel

I've got a project that is a couple of years old (rails 4) that I'm trying to update (all for the sake of active admin's datetime select not working) -- when I comment out the need to update squeel it all updates fine; but if I uncomment out squeel so that it too updates I get these dependency issues:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
```

In Gemfile:
    acts-as-taggable-on was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0)

```
annotate was resolved to 2.7.1, which depends on
  activerecord (< 6.0, >= 3.2)

friendly_id (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

pg_search was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
  activerecord (>= 3.1)

polyamorous was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
  activerecord (>= 3.0)

polyamorous was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
  activerecord (>= 3.0)

rails (~> 4.2.1) was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
  activerecord (= 4.2.1)

rails-erd was resolved to 1.4.7, which depends on
  activerecord (>= 3.2)

random_record was resolved to 0.0.8, which depends on
  activerecord (>= 3.0.0)

squeel was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
  activerecord (~> 3.1.0.alpha)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "polyamorous":
  In Gemfile:
    polyamorous

```
ransack was resolved to 1.8.1, which depends on
  polyamorous (~> 1.3)

squeel was resolved to 0.8.10, which depends on
  polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap-sass (~> 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1.1, which depends on
      sass (~> 3.2)

```
activeadmin was resolved to 1.0.0.pre4, which depends on
  bourbon was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
    sass (~> 3.3)

sass-rails (~> 4.0.1) was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
  sass (~> 3.2.2)
```

I've tried a few different combinations of active admin such as:

```
# gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre2'
# gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

or

```
# gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'active_admin_datetimepicker'
gem "active_admin-sortable_tree"
gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
```

and

```
# gem "squeel"  # Last officially released gem
# gem 'squeel', github: 'activerecord-hackery/squeel'
# gem "squeel", :git => "git://github.com/ernie/squeel.git" # Track git repo
```

But nothing seems to be working....

Comment: You aren't trying to upgrade to rails 5 by any chance, are you?

Comment: Nope, for me it's 4.2

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still at it (Rails 5 upgrade) you might want to try adding `activeresource` to your `Gemfile` explicitly. Like so:

```
gem 'activeresource', github: 'rails/activeresource'

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
```

The update did work for me, at least so far, and without using additional dependencies such as ransack, draper etc. even though it is recommended to on their (ActiveAdmin's) official [README](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin).

Give it a try.